# Pass data via EventEmitter in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a variable with EventEmitter between 2 components, I have these 2 piece of code in 2 different .component files (I have removed boilerplate code):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'shopping-list-item',
    template: `
        <form #f="ngForm">
            <div class="input">
                <label for="item-name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="item-name" ngControl="inputname">
            </div>  
            <div class="input">
                <label for="item-amt">Amount</label>
                <input type="text" id="item-amt" ngControl="inputamount">
            </div>
            <button class="info" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
        </form>
        `,
        inputs:['item'],
        outputs:['editted']
})

export class ShoppingListItemComponent {
    item = { name: '', amount: 0 };
    editted = new EventEmitter({name: form['inputname'], amount: form['inputamount'] });

    onEdit(){
        this.editted.emit(this.item);
    }
}





@Component({
    selector: 'shopping-list',
    template: `
        <section>
            <div class="list">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#listItem of listItems" (click)="onSelect(listItem)">{{listItem.name}} ({{listItem.amount}})</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <shopping-list-item [item] (editted)="onEditItem($event)"></shopping-list-item>
        </section>
    `
})
export class ShoppingListComponent {
    onEditItem(item:ListItem){
        let myindex = this.listItems.indexOf(item);
        this.listItems[myindex].name = +$event.name;
        this.listItems[myindex].amount = +$event.amount;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error during evaluation of "editted". `$event is not defined`
```

If I replace `+$event.name` with a value like "test" it I don't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done seems almost wrong. To guide you in a proper direction you can check this answer.
 EventEmitter is generally used to propagate data from `child to parent` component.
In your case, `shoppinlistitem` will propagate data to `shoppinglist` component like this,

[see this working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nAeepqZpYkAeJQvsYzyU?p=preview)

Note :  *please ignore improper naming conventions and what Gunter has suggested is correct*.

**shoppinglist.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
directives:[shoppinglistitem], 
template: `

<h2>shopping-list</h2>    
{{item|json}}
<shopping-list-item (editted)="onEditItem($event)"></shopping-list-item>
`
})

export class BodyContent {

    name:string='Angular1';
    onEditItem(arg){
            console.log('onEditedItem started');
             console.log(arg);
             this.item=arg;
        }
 }

bootstrap(BodyContent, []);
```

**shoppinglistitem.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'shopping-list-item',  
template: `
<hr>
      <h4>ShoppinglistItem</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="info" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
<hr>
  `
})

export class shoppinglistitem {
     item = { name: 'micronyks', amount: '0' };

    @Output() editted: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

      constructor() {
        console.log('Constructor called');
      }

      onEdit()
      {
        this.editted.emit(this.item);
      }
}
```

Comment: Answer doesn't contain full solution. But surely will help you to go ahead. Almost I have don't what you were looking for. Remaning things can be completed by you.

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid

```
new EventEmitter({name: form['inputname'], amount: form['inputamount'] });
```

`EventEmitter` only supports one contructor argument

```
export class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T> {
  ...

  constructor(isAsync: boolean = true)
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14f0e9ada8b23e6cb4dd4cf4ce1127e9c9180476/modules/angular2/src/facade/async.ts#L108